# Saving a comment object to a post in a blog in django database

Tags: python-2.7, django-models, django-views

I am  making a simple post and comment page.In this,when i comment on a post i am trying to save that comment on the database.I am retrieving the title of the post on which comment is made by using its id.But when i try to instantiate the post_title attribute of Post_Comment by doing  comments.post_title=header.title it gives a value eror saying Cannot assign "u'kjashdkh'": "Post_Comment.post_title" must be a "Post" instance. Please note that "kjashdkh" is the post title.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField (max_length=100)

    body= models.TextField ()

    created=models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Post_Comment(models.Model):
    comment= models.TextField() 
    post_title=models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

And my view is:

```
def comment(request,pk):
    header=Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    comments=Post_Comment(comment=request.POST['comment'])
    comments.post_title=header.title
    header.delete()

    comments.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')
```

Comment: Well? The error is pretty clear. You've set `post_title=models.ForeignKey(Post)` so it expects a `Post` object but you're giving it `header.title` which is a `CharField`, or a string object. Seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how foreign keys in Django work. Have you read through the tutorial?

Comment: Thanks man.I am a little new at using foreignkey.But how should i rectify this problem.

Comment: I guess you could `comments.post_title = header` but you can't then delete the blog post (`header.delete()`) on the next line. You should consider more accurate variable names. Calling a blog post "header" and a reference to it later "post_title" makes this very confusing to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def comment(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)

    comment = Post_Comment.objects.create(post_title=post, comment=request.POST['comment'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')
```

Take care about naming. Your models should rather be in a way like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField() 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
```

Comment: I am not getting as for what purpose related_name is added

Comment: Just for convenience... You can use that name for the reverse relations: `post.comments.all()`.

Comment: Yeah got it.Finally. Just one more question. I am using listview to show all the recent posts,and for that the queryset i am providing is from Post model.I am asking can i set the query set to Post_Comment model and using its post attribute access the Post model.So that my all my posts and their respective comments will all be shown using a single urlconfiguration

Comment: You don't have to. In the template just display the comments for each post...
`{% for comment in post.comments.all %}{{ comment }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: I have already done that.Its not working.Because i dont think we can do post.comment when our queryset is using Post model which do not have comment attribute

Comment: it is `post.comments` not `post.comment`. and yes - this works. thats what `related_name` is for. it adds a backward-relation to your foreign key.